# removing bracket value from first and adding some data to second column

Tags: linux

I want to remove all the brackets value from first column and add some field in last column

```
Sample Input
EXAMPLE(abc@gmail.com),60,6
EXAMPLE(bcd@gmail.com),30,6
EXAMPLE1(sample@gmail.com),60,3

Sample Output

EXAMPLE,60,6.ABC
EXAMPLE,30,6,ABC
EXAMPLE1,60,3,ABC
```

Below is code which I tried but no luck :

```
 for file_name in tmp/*.csv
    do
       sed -i 's/$/,"AB"/' "$file_name"| awk '{sub(/[(].*[)]/,"")}1' $file_name > tmp.csv && mv tmp.csv $file_name
    done
```

when I try it with single file it is working but in look it is not working:

```
sed -i 's/$/,"AB"/' abc.csv| awk '{sub(/[(].*[)]/,"")}1' abc.csv > tmp.csv
```

Comment: Any one plz help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will do:

```
awk '{sub(/[(].*[)]/,""); print $0",ABC"}' file | awk '{sub(/60,6,/,"60,6.")}1'

EXAMPLE,60,6.ABC
EXAMPLE,30,6,ABC
EXAMPLE1,60,3,ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/tmp> cat jyoti.txt
EXAMPLE(abc@gmail.com),60,6
EXAMPLE(bcd@gmail.com),30,6
EXAMPLE1(sample@gmail.com),60,3
/tmp> perl -lne  's/\(.*\)//; print "$_,ABC" ' jyoti.txt
EXAMPLE,60,6,ABC
EXAMPLE,30,6,ABC
EXAMPLE1,60,3,ABC
/tmp>
```